# How would I use Tasker to boot my PC when I get home?

Tags: windows, tasker

I have an Android phone running the Tasker app. I have a home computer running Windows 7 as well. Is there any way I can have Tasker detect that I've arrived at home, and send a "Wake On LAN" packet to the computer somehow? What configuration do I need to do on Tasker and on the PC itself to support this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check out this [wake on LAN plugin](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.steelgirder.LocaleWOLPlugin/Locale-Wake-On-Lan-Plug-In-Fre) for Tasker / Locale. (Haven't tried it - would be interested to hear how you get on if you give it a go)

Comment: Downloading it now;  will try it when I get home today.

Comment: @GWLlosa did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, but it was kind of hit-or-miss.  Mostly cause it turned out my locale itself on that phone was hit or miss;  Samsung Galaxy S had GPS issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not using tasker, but the following may also work:

http://lifehacker.com/#!5796450/automatically-turn-on-your-pc-over-wi+fi-with-pcautowaker-on-android